# How to return results with an API

Tags: php, node.js, api

I'm doing some tests in PHP to make an api and use it from nodejs,

i did something like :

```
<?php

function test () {
    $var = 'School';

    return json_encode($var);
}

echo test();
```

?>

it works great,

so my question is : do I need to display my response (with echo) ?

I get my results in nodejs. if I don't display my data with echo I receive an empty result.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: yes, this is the only place in your code you output anything

Answer (score 3):

Yes. You may also want to send headers what sort of data you're returning (for example, `application/json` Content-Type) using `header` function (before `echo`ing anything).